# Powershell xml replacement teg using foreach

Tags: xml, powershell, foreach

I have an XML subscription to a SQL Reporting Server report. Below is the XML part:

```
     <Objs Version="1.1.0.1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/2004/04">
  <Obj RefId="0">
    <TN RefId="0">
      <T>System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject</T>
      <T>System.Object</T>
    </TN>
    <MS>
      <S N="EventType">TimedSubscription</S>
      <S N="SubscriptionID">0cd266b0-ecbe-41e0-b3a8-0118a6e1066c</S>
      <DT N="ModifiedDate">2022-04-11T18:16:41.677</DT>
      <B N="LastExecutedSpecified">false</B>
      <S N="Report">Subscription Director</S>
      <S N="Status">New Subscription</S>
      <Obj N="Active" RefId="1">
        <TN RefId="1">
          <T>Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewWebserviceProxy.AutogeneratedTypes.WebServiceProxy1Reports_ReportService2010_asmx.ActiveState</T>
          <T>System.Object</T>
        </TN>
        <ToString>Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewWebserviceProxy.AutogeneratedTypes.WebServiceProxy1Reports_ReportService2010_asmx.ActiveState</ToString>
        <Props>
          <B N="DeliveryExtensionRemoved">false</B>
          <B N="DeliveryExtensionRemovedSpecified">false</B>
          <B N="SharedDataSourceRemoved">false</B>
          <B N="SharedDataSourceRemovedSpecified">false</B>
          <B N="MissingParameterValue">false</B>
          <B N="MissingParameterValueSpecified">false</B>
          <B N="InvalidParameterValue">false</B>
          <B N="InvalidParameterValueSpecified">false</B>
          <B N="UnknownReportParameter">false</B>
          <B N="UnknownReportParameterSpecified">false</B>
          <B N="DisabledByUser">false</B>
          <B N="DisabledByUserSpecified">false</B>
        </Props>
      </Obj>
      <Nil N="VirtualPath" />
      <S N="ModifiedBy">domain\admin</S>
      <S N="Description">User</S>
      <DT N="LastExecuted">0001-01-01T00:00:00</DT>
      <Obj N="Values" RefId="2">
        <TN RefId="2">
          <T>Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewWebserviceProxy.AutogeneratedTypes.WebServiceProxy1Reports_ReportService2010_asmx.ParameterValue[]</T>
          <T>System.Array</T>
          <T>System.Object</T>
        </TN>
        <LST />
      </Obj>
    </MS>
    <!--..........-->
  </Obj>
</Objs>
```

There are many such strings in XML. I want to replace `<LST/>`with

```
<LST>
<Obj N="Values" RefId ="3">
<TN RefId ="3">    <T>MIcrosoft.Powershell.Commands.NewWebserviceProxy.AutogeneratedTypes.WebServiceProxyReports_ReportService2010_asmx.ParameterValue</T>
<T>MIcrosoft.Powershell.Commands.NewWebserviceProxy.AutogeneratedTypes.WebServiceProxyReports_ReportService2010_asmx.ParameterValueOfFieldReference</T>
        <T>System.Object</T>
<TN/>
<ToString>MIcrosoft.Powershell.Commands.NewWebserviceProxy.AutogeneratedTypes.WebServiceProxyReports_ReportService2010_asmx.ParameterValue</ToString>
<Props>
<S N="Name">name</S>
<S N="Value">UserName</S>
<Nil N="Label">
</Obj>
    </LST>
```

Used the following query:

```
 $XML =Get-Content '\\share\test.xml'
    Foreach ($LST in $xml)
    {
    $_ -replace @"
    <LST />"@,
    @"
 <LST>
<Obj N="Values" RefId ="3">
<TN RefId ="3">    <T>MIcrosoft.Powershell.Commands.NewWebserviceProxy.AutogeneratedTypes.WebServiceProxyReports_ReportService2010_asmx.ParameterValue</T>
<T>MIcrosoft.Powershell.Commands.NewWebserviceProxy.AutogeneratedTypes.WebServiceProxyReports_ReportService2010_asmx.ParameterValueOfFieldReference</T>
        <T>System.Object</T>
<TN/>
<ToString>MIcrosoft.Powershell.Commands.NewWebserviceProxy.AutogeneratedTypes.WebServiceProxyReports_ReportService2010_asmx.ParameterValue</ToString>
<Props>
<S N="Name">name</S>
<S N="Value">UserName</S>
<Nil N="Label">
</Obj>
    </LST>
    "@
    }
    Out-file '\\share\test.xml'
```

The goal is to get such a result in the entire file test.xml

```
 <Obj N="Values" RefId ="2">
      <TN RefId ="2"> <T>MIcrosoft.Powershell.Commands.NewWebserviceProxy.AutogeneratedTypes.WebServiceProxyReports_ReportService2010_asmx.ParameterValue[]</T>
        <T>System.Array</T>
        <T>System.Object</T>
      </TN>
    <LST>
    <Obj N="Values" RefId ="3">
    <TN RefId ="3">    <T>MIcrosoft.Powershell.Commands.NewWebserviceProxy.AutogeneratedTypes.WebServiceProxyReports_ReportService2010_asmx.ParameterValue</T>
    <T>MIcrosoft.Powershell.Commands.NewWebserviceProxy.AutogeneratedTypes.WebServiceProxyReports_ReportService2010_asmx.ParameterValueOfFieldReference</T>
        <T>System.Object</T>
    <TN/>
    <ToString>MIcrosoft.Powershell.Commands.NewWebserviceProxy.AutogeneratedTypes.WebServiceProxyReports_ReportService2010_asmx.ParameterValue</ToString>
    <Props>
    <S N="Name">name</S>
    <S N="Value">UserName</S>
    <Nil N="Label">
    </Obj>
    </LST>
    </Obj>
```

for a comment:
[image]

How to fix the script?

Answer (score 0):

The xml fragment you are trying to append is not well-formed. Assuming the actual form is like the one below, one way you can get your expected output is this:

```
#EDIT
$xml=[Xml]@"
<Obj N="Values" RefId ="2">
      <TN RefId ="2">
          <T>MIcrosoft.Powershell.Commands.NewWebserviceProxy.AutogeneratedTypes.WebServiceProxyReports_ReportService2010_asmx.ParameterValue[]</T>
        <T>System.Array</T>
        <T>System.Object</T>
      </TN>
      <LST />
    </Obj>
"@

$LST=@'
      <LST>
    <Obj N="Values" RefId ="3">
      <TN RefId ="3"> 
        <T>MIcrosoft.Powershell.Commands.NewWebserviceProxy.AutogeneratedTypes.WebServiceProxyReports_ReportService2010_asmx.ParameterValue
        </T>
        <T>MIcrosoft.Powershell.Commands.NewWebserviceProxy.AutogeneratedTypes.WebServiceProxyReports_ReportService2010_asmx.ParameterValueOfFieldReference
        </T>
        <T>System.Object
        </T>
      </TN>
      <ToString>MIcrosoft.Powershell.Commands.NewWebserviceProxy.AutogeneratedTypes.WebServiceProxyReports_ReportService2010_asmx.ParameterValue
      </ToString>
      <Props>
        <S N="Name">name
        </S>
        <S N="Value">UserName
        </S>
      </Props>
    </Obj>
  </LST>
'@

#EDIT 2
$node = $xml.SelectSingleNode('//*[local-name()="LST"]') 
$dest = $node.ParentNode
$dest.RemoveChild($node)

$xmlFragment=$xml.CreateDocumentFragment()
$xmlFragment.InnerXML=$LST
$dest.AppendChild($xmlFragment)
```

Comment: Appear error: "You cannot a method on a null-valued expression" for line `$dest.RemoveChild($node)` and `$dest.AppendChild($xmlFragment)`. Is it because node lst has 4 parents?

Comment: @Majorov I guess your `$xml` is not the same as mine. See edit.

Comment: Yes, my XML is bigger. Added to the question.

Comment: @Majorov Well, your actual xml has a namespace declaration, which makes things more difficult.... See Edit 2.

Comment: ,please tell me how to select only empty LST? When requesting `$node = $xml.SelectNodes('//*[local-name()="LST"]') 
$dest = $node.ParentNode
$dest`, I get a result on the screen in the question.

Comment: @Majorov I'm sorry, but I don't understand your question.

Comment: Thank you, I solved the problem not very nicely, but it worked.  `$xml = $xml -replace '<LST />', $new |Out-file  '.\file.xml'`